# Arcmap 10 modelbuilder convert string variable to uppercase than call in SQL expression

Tags: python, sql, arcmap

This might seem like an easy fix and I'm relatively new to SQL and Python scripting. I've created a model in arcmap 10.1 that selects records from a feature class based on a user input. The model parameter that asks for input from the user is a string variable. This variable is being used in two separate SELECT tools. This first one (SELECT LAND)works just fine using the following code:

Client Name is the parameter and is called using inline variable substitution
SQL Expression: "OWNERSHIP" LIKE '%%Client Name%%'

The next feature class (GL_WELLS.shp) requires all UPPERCASE letters in order to return records. The first one requires only the first character by uppercase. This is where the tool errors out every time, on the SELECT WELLS tool.

I've tried a few different things in python and sql to force uppercase and I haven't had any luck. I've tried using other string variables to transition as well as the calculate value tool. I think the inline variable substitution is casing me the headache.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ywX7.jpg -> I need 10 rep to post images :(

Hopefully this image helps. that box in the bottom can use SQL expressions or python. The output can be called in the rest of the model using %Client Name2%. I've run out of ideas and the obvious string.upper() or UPPER("string") isn't working for me and I feel the answer is pretty obvious :/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your sql expression, try this:

```
"CUR_OPER" LIKE UPPER('%ClientName%')
```